# Cannot Set Multi Text color for text view using Html.fromText in < 24

Tags: android

I have seen all around stackoverflow to use

```
setText(html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#c5c5c5\">Hello</font>"))
```

However none of these work for android < 23

here is a sample code:

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(context);
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p style=\"color:red;\">Test</p>"));
```

This sets font color in > 23. Is there any alternatives that work for < 23? or is this a bug with the following dependency?

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Some more info: I am testing on Lolipop x86 image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for HTML, just use spans.

```java
Spannable text = new SpannableString("hello");
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
mTextView.setText(text);
```

If you're using appcompat, you probably want to `new AppCompatTextView(context)` rather than just `new TextView(context)`.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the problem is I have a long line and I want to set different colors to different words of unknown size is there a good way to do this? with Html its much easier to do this

Comment: @Android You can call `setSpan` on the different regions, `setSpan(redSpan, words[0], words[1], flags); setSpan(greenSpan, words[1], words[2], flags); // etc.`

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
setText(Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<font color='#c5c5c5'>Hello</font>]]>"));
```

for xml layout remember to add

```
android:textAllCaps="true"
```